# Init function only runs every second time

Tags: angularjs

For some strange reason the ini() function runs only every second time. 
I have this issue in another app as well...

I have no idea why.

My code:

```
<ion-view ng-init="ini()">
  <ion-header-bar class="banner-top ext-box" align-title="left">
    <div class="int-box2"><h2 id="s_back1">MAP STORIES</h2></div>
  </ion-header-bar>
<ion-content overflow-scroll="true" class="has-header has-footer no-bgColor" scroll="false" >
```

JS

```
.controller('MapCtrl', function($scope, $state, $http) {

  $scope.ini = function() {
    $http({
            method : "GET",
            url : "https://domain.ch/pois.php"
        }).then(function mySucces(response) {
            console.log("success");
        }, function myError(response) {
            $state.go("error");
        });
  }


})
```

Route

```
.state('map', {
    url: '/map',
    templateUrl: 'templates/map.html',
    controller: "MapCtrl"
  })
```

Comment: Why don't you do that request in the route's `resolve` ?

Comment: Sorry i'm a beginner with angular. Could you make an example or share a tutorial?

Comment: @olvier When data is required for your state to function it's advised to load that while loading the state instead of in an `init` function, please have a look at [this link](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve)